# Design a monitoring system with 1 million node to monitor

Tags: architecture, software-design

This is one of the design interview question where I could not convince interviewer. I would like to know what are design aspect we could think with below system.

**Design System which will monitor 1 million system "remotely" every 10 sec.**

Here are few points from approach

- Client/Server architecture. where client will be monitored systems and server would be Agent which is monitoring all systems
- As cost of persistent connection would more, no persistent connection.
- Client will send all information to server at very first cycle and send delta only if there is change.
- TO reduce a load on single agent, can have multiple agents which will monitor monitored system.
- Load balancing will be done by "leader" agent.
- Client will be notified with Agent IP to whom it needs to communicate.
- On failure of any agent, "Leader" will redistribute agent assigned to failed node. In this case, client will be notified with new agent IP, client will resend all details in first cycle and subsequent cycle send all details.

Is that approach good, what all other things can be considered in such system?